# Kata 7 Largest 5 digit number in a series

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python IDLE returns answer correctly but codewars tells "digits = math.log10(number)+1 
                                                         TypeError: must be real number, not str"

```
import math

def solution(number):
    ind = 0
    numbers = []
    digits = int(math.log10(number))+1
    number=str(number)
    for i in range(digits-4):
        num = number[ind:ind+5]
        ind+=1
        numbers.append(num)

    return max(numbers)
```

Comment: How do you call your `solution` fucntion? It seems that a string has been given to it, not a number.

Comment: @ex4 OP does not mention it, but "Kata" means this code is executed by an online judge on a certain competitive programming website. OP has no control over how the function is called and what arguments it is given.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `number` is a string. You should convert it to an integer.

```
digits = int(math.log10(int(number))) + 1
```

It also means you can delete this line

```
number = str(number)
```

because `number` is already `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier do it like this?

```
def solution(numberstr):
    values = [numberstr[i:i+5] for i in range(len(numberstr)-4)]
    values.sort()
    return values[-1]
```